# How to display stored image in database on page in google app engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I have uploaded image on GAE non-rel database. I am using python-django.

**Model.py**

`class UploadImages(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to=image/user/)`

Now i get this table data using queryset and try to display image on html page.

```
{% for img in images %}
        <div class="superbox-list">
            <img src="{{ img.image }}" alt=" " title="    {{ img.description }}" class="superbox-img">
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

But the image is not displaying. What i have to do to display image in GAE-django project.

Answer (score -1):

To handle the src link of your `<img>` You need a handler.

A better option is to use Google Cloudstorage. Google will serve the image for you at very low cost, without writing your own handler. With GCS you can resize and crop the image using a [serving url](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions). In your model you only have to store this serving url once.

Example code shown [here](https://gist.github.com/voscausa/9541133).